# Show [CODE] instead of the actual code in the question preview

Tags: feature-request, questions, code-formatting, information-display

I think that when somebody adds some code to their question on Stack Exchange, in the question preview you shouldn't be able to actually read it, but instead you should see just "[CODE]" or something similar.

An image of the current behavior:

[image: preview of question with a block of raw unformatted code taking up most of the snippet]

As you can see, this takes away most of the question, and makes it much harder to see what's being asked or what the post is really about.

You could get a better preview and idea of the question if you didn't see illegible code (because of the format it is very difficult to read at a glance!).

You could instead see something like this:

[image: preview of same question with codeblock replaced with "codeblock" in square brackets; more of the English text of the question is visible]

Answer (score 14):

I assume you're envisioning something like this:

[image]

If so, I totally agree with you - the code isn't really readable in the snippet, and adding more of the question text lets a user possibly tell easier if they can answer the question or not without visiting the question page.